# Configuring commons logging in Glassfish

Tags: glassfish-3, apache-commons-logging

I am using commons logging for my application running on Glassfish V3.1(I am new to glassfish).  I have different applications running on Glassfish under ../domain1 folder(Developers machine). I am using an XML to configure Logging.Following is the my xml config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="file"
        class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="100KB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="File" value="/home/phanikumar/Desktop/debug.log" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d{DATE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="warn" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="fatal" />
        </filter>

    </appender>
     <logger name="com">
        <level value="DEBUG" />     
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </logger>

    <root>

        <appender-ref ref="file" />

    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

In this config file I have explicitly mentioned the file to be in a specific location but it never did.Is there any problem with the logger file?Am I missing some thing?

or

Is there any way that I can configure my logs to be in a specific location? I have seen the server.log file and it is unsuitable for my requirement as the logs of all applications are logged in a same file.

Please kindly help me.

Comment: Have you checked the server.log for errors? Try changing the file location to just a file name and see if it shows up.. maybe you have a path error.

Comment: @Preston I have checked the log but I didnt find any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Add a Properties file named ***commons-logging.properties*** in the class path.

And add the following property

> org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger

This initializes Logging to Log4j Logger

Then it works perfectly.

**EDIT:**
Usually, by default commons logging searches for loggers like log4j. If the above solution doesnt work, one needs to check if the commons-logging jar file is corrupted i.e, check if the class files like org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jLogger is present.